# Node JS getting comments user info using Graph API

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why is it that when I query page posts on graph api, some posts don't have a "from" field on their comments especially on the photo posts. Has anyone else experienced this problem? Same thing happens when I fetch it using my app and using the graph api explorer. I can get the text of the comment, the created_time, etc., but I there is no "from" which is the info of the one who sent the comment. This is happening on some posts only, not on all, and it happens on photo posts only, but still not on all photo posts. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a page access token for the page in question for all those requests?

Comment: yes. i was already using page access token when this issue arose. it's just weird that it happens only on some photo posts, but on others it doesn't. Like if i use my fb account to comment on a text only post on the page, I can get the "from" field of the comment, but when I use the same fb account to comment on a profile picture of the page, i don't get the "from" field of the comment.